# trying to use threads to make the mandelbrot set faster by splitting the function that computes the image into 2 thread but i can't get it to work

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
const int WIDTH = 1920;
const int HEIGHT = 1200;


const int MAX_ITERATIONS = 500;

uint32_t image[HEIGHT][WIDTH];


struct ThreadArgs { int id; int delay; };
void myThreadFunc(ThreadArgs args)

{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        sleep_for(seconds(args.delay));
        cout << args.id;
    }
}
void write_tga(const char *filename)
{
    ofstream outfile(filename, ofstream::binary);

    uint8_t header[18] = {
        0, // no image ID
        0, // no colour map
        2, // uncompressed 24-bit image
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // empty colour map specification
        0, 0, // X origin
        0, 0, // Y origin
        WIDTH & 0xFF, (WIDTH >> 8) & 0xFF, // width
        HEIGHT & 0xFF, (HEIGHT >> 8) & 0xFF, // height
        24, // bits per pixel
        0, // image descriptor
    };
    outfile.write((const char *)header, 18);

    for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x)
        {
            uint8_t pixel[3] = {
                image[y][x] & 0xFF, // blue channel
                (image[y][x] >> 8) & 0xFF, // green channel
                (image[y][x] >> 16) & 0xFF, // red channel
            };
            outfile.write((const char *)pixel, 3);
        }
    }

    outfile.close();
    if (!outfile)
    {

        cout << "Error writing to " << filename << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}



void compute_mandelbrot(double left, double right, double top, double bottom)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x)
        {

            complex<double> c(left + (x * (right - left) / WIDTH),
                top + (y * (bottom - top) / HEIGHT));


            complex<double> z(0.0, 0.0);


            int iterations = 0;
            while (abs(z) < 2.0 && iterations < MAX_ITERATIONS)
            {
                z = (z * z) + c;

                ++iterations;
            }

            if (iterations == MAX_ITERATIONS)
            {

                image[y][x] = 0x000000; // black
            }
            else
            {

                image[y][x] = 0xFFFFFF; // white
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is most of the code and this works but i want to make it run faster using more threads.

i tried splitting the height portions of the compute_mandelbrot function into two separate functions but could not get it to not flag errors. the errors i got were: "expression must be a modifiable lvalue" and "array type 'uint32_t[1920]' is not assignable" on the line "image[x] = 0x000000 ' the same happened on the other lines mentioning image[x] or image[y] as I'd changed those lines to split the function between x axis and y axis. The above code does not have this change

is there any way to do this or something like this to split this function between two threads? if so please explain

Comment: "_but could not get it to not flag error_": it is useful for people trying to help to know that these errors are. Can you add the error messages to your question?

Comment: @rodrigo added the error messages and explained what caused them when I altered the code

Answer (score 0):

Compilers don't guess at your code. `uint32_t image[HEIGHT][WIDTH];` is a 2D array of pixels. `image[y][x]` is single pixel. `image[y]` is a row of pixels. And you can't assign a whole row of pixels. `image[x]` is still a row of pixels. The compile won't turn that into a column just because you used `x`.

It's indeed easy to split the function in two threads. Just calculate the upper and lower half of the image separately, changing just the `for(int y ...` part.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it